# Full text search PHP alone

Tags: php, string, full-text-search, sorting

I have an InnoDB table from which values are retrieved and stored in an array in PHP.

Now I want to sort the array by relevance to the matches in the search string.

eg: If I search "hai how are you", it will split the string into separate words as "hai" "how" "are" "you" and the results after search must be as follows:

```
 [0] hai how are all people there

 [1] how are things going 

 [2] are you coming

 [3] how is sam
```

...

Is there any way I can sort the array by relevance in basic PHP functions alone?

Comment: You could look into `similar_text()`
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchText = "hai how      are you"; //eg: if there are multiple spaces between words
$searchText = preg_replace("(\s+)", " ", $searchText );
$searchArray =& split( " ", $searchText );

$text = array(0 => 'hai how are all people there',
              1 => 'how are things going ',
              2 => 'are you coming',
              3 => 'how is sam',
              4 => 'testing ggg');

foreach($text as $key=>$elt){
    foreach($searchArray as $searchelt){
        if(strpos($elt,$searchelt)!== FALSE){
            $matches[] =  $key;  //just storing key to avoid memory wastage
            break;
        }                
    }            
}

//print the matched string with help of stored keys
echo '<pre>matched string are as follows: ';
foreach ($matches as $key){

  echo "<br>{$text[$key]}";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$arrayToSort=array(); //define your array here
$query="hai how are you";

function compare($arrayMember1,$arrayMember2){
     $a=similar_text($arrayMember1,$query);
     $b=similar_text($arrayMember2,$query);
     if($a>$b)return 1;
     else return -1;
}

usort($arrayToSort,"compare");
```

Look in the php manual for clarification on what similar_text and usort do.

Comment: your $query variable wont be accessible directly in compare(). you need to do this.
function compare($arrayMember1,$arrayMember2){
    global $query;                                                                    }

Comment: when i just compared str1 = "testing ggg" ,str2="hai how are you" similar_text() => returns 2 and the percent of similarity: 15.384615384615

Comment: I wrote 'maybe something like this', implying I'm giving only ideas. Don't expect me to do the job completely, unless, of course, he/she pay me.

Comment: and about the similar_text function, I'm sure comparing "how" and "hai how ..." will return bigger value than your test. and don't compete for a better solution :) Infact I would reccomend your approach because mine is way more inefficient. but he/she wanted a solution with existing php function